# ParcelJs add extra "/" before all files link

Tags: javascript, npm, parceljs

I'm actually working on a ts project with ParcelJs. When I build my project and open it on the ParcelJs server on `http://localhost:1234/` everything work great. But when I try to open it outside this server all my files are not found because there is an extra `/` at the beginning of each file link.

For example ParcelJs give in my index.html links like this that do not work:

`<script src="/src.4254afb6.js"></script>`

But when I remove this `/` like this everything is working as expected:

`<script src="src.4254afb6.js"></script>`

So what have I to do to fix it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make all links relative (with no `/`) you will need to add an extra parameter `--public-url` with the value `./` when you run **ParcelJs** like this :

`parcel index.html  --public-url ./`